# SQL Server date function

Tags: sql-server, date

I need to get the week number of the giving date. For Ex jan 1 = week no is 1, Jan 8 - week 2 like this.. any one help me out pls.

Comment: Check [FiscalWeek](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/returning-a-week-number-for-any-given-date-and-starting-fiscal-month) function in the linked [page](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/returning-a-week-number-for-any-given-date-and-starting-fiscal-month).

Answer (score 5):

You should try something like  this:

```
DECLARE @Dt datetime
SELECT @Dt='02-21-2008'
SELECT DATEPART( wk, @Dt)
```

This should return the weeknumbers you want.

SQL Server starts counting from the 1st of january. If you want to return the ISO weeknumbers, you need to do a bit more scripting. A nice howto is listed in this site: http://www.rmjcs.com/SQLServer/TSQLFunctions/ISOWeekNumber/tabid/207/Default.aspx

**MSDN**: [`DATEPART (Transact-SQL)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

In response to Robin's comment:

> But i need in such a way, that from
>   jan 1 to 7, it should return 1, from
>   jan 8 to 17 it should return 2 like
>   this.. hope u got my impression

In that case you could also write something like this.

```
select (datepart(dy, '2011-01-01') / 7) + 1
--returns 1
select (datepart(dy, '2011-01-02') / 7) + 1
--returns 1
select (datepart(dy, '2011-12-31') / 7) + 1
--returns 53
```

I don't know how SQL Server 2008 responds with the `iso_week` and `wk` parameter as I only got a SQL 2005 instance available at the moment.

Comment: `datepart(iso_week, @dt)` does the same as `udf_GetISOWeekNumberFromDate` from the link.

Comment: This is working, But i dont need in this way. If u pass 1 jan 2011, it will return 1, for 2jan 2011 it will return 2. Thats true. But i need in such a way, that from jan 1 to 7, it should return 1, from jan 8 to 17 it should return 2 like this.. hope u got my impression

Comment: @Mikael Thanks, didn't know about that one. I see it was implemented since SQL Server 2008. Nice

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
declare @T table (dt datetime)
insert into @T values
('2010-12-31'),
('2011-01-01'),
('2011-01-02'),
('2011-01-03'),
('2011-01-04'),
('2011-01-05'),
('2011-01-06'),
('2011-01-07'),
('2011-01-08')

select
  dt,
  (datediff(d, dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, dt), 0), dt) / 7)+1
from @T
```

Result

```
dt                      
----------------------- -----------
2010-12-31 00:00:00.000 53
2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 1
2011-01-02 00:00:00.000 1
2011-01-03 00:00:00.000 1
2011-01-04 00:00:00.000 1
2011-01-05 00:00:00.000 1
2011-01-06 00:00:00.000 1
2011-01-07 00:00:00.000 1
2011-01-08 00:00:00.000 2
```